# How to have 2 different web/app servers for the same domain but different context path?

Tags: apache, http, wildfly-8

I'm running a standard PHP application on my domain and did set that to `www.johndoe.com/p/`

Now, the port 80 is apparently serviced by this HTTP server (Apache, not Tomcat). Also, I installed Wildfly 8.2 on this server on port 8000. How, can I use Wildfly WAR applications on the same domain e.g. `www.johndoe.com/w/`?

I'm positive that there is a way of redirecting the **/w/** requests to the Java EE server and keep the **/p/** serviced by Apache, right?

I assume mod_proxy (http gateway) and mod_proxy_ajp are simple solutions. Can anyone reflect on my requirements and the the mod_proxy/ajp functionality?

```
ProxyPass /w ajp://localhost:8000/w
ProxyPassReverse /w http://www.johndoe.com/w
```

I do not demand load balacing or anything else sophisticated. Just the split of the two contexti. Only port 80 is accessible from the internet.

Thank you.

Comment: If you will type `www.johndoe.com/p/` or `www.johndoe.com/w/` in browser it should and will be serviced by apache and if you will type the same but with specific  port (`www.johndoe.com:8000/p/`) it must be serviced by wildfly

Comment: @winston86 Yes, it does. Yes, but on my server port 8000 is closed. So I need to go thru 80. Just asking if it is as simple as writing those 2 ProxyPass lines to Apache HTTP Server (and active AJP in Wildfly).

Comment: It's no way to do so. Wildfly must listen on some interface and port. You need to allow in your firewall settings accept and return data via port 8000. You can redirect `www.johndoe.com/p/`  to `www.johndoe.com:8000/p/` but the packets will be droped because of firewall.

Comment: @winston86 Why should that be the case? It's the same server. Once the request is within the firewall, with the Apache Server, it can use any protocol and hostname. e.g. ajp://localhost:8000/w

Also, I try to route for http://www.johndoe.com/w and not for ...doe.com/p

Comment: Well you can try to redirect via loopback interface but still the same problem you need to allow 8000 port on interface in firewall and set wildfly to listen on it . But if you need to interact with wildfly the output packets will be droped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Here the resolution.

I added to Wildfly 8.2 standalone.xml the following ajp-listener...

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
    <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
        <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
        <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
    </host>
</server>
```

... and bind it to the socket ...

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:28009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:28080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:28443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="mail.johndoe.com" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Invoke `service wildfly reload` or `service wildfly restart`. To Wildfly listening on AJP requests.

Finally, add to your http.conf file of your Apache Virtual Host Domain the following:

```
ProxyPass /w ajp://127.0.0.1:28009/w
ProxyPassReverse /w ajp://127.0.0.1:28009/w
```

Also for Apache, restart with `service apache2 reload`.

Caution. In Parallels Plesk, the virtual host config file must be edited in /var/www/vhosts/system/johndoe.com/conf/http.conf and NOT in /var/vhosts/johndoe.com/conf/http.conf

Comment: Very clear and straight to the point. It worked perfectly for me